# I have 2 elements inside a div element and 1 has visibility set to hidden. Onclick I want the hidden one to become visible but it is not doing this

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have a div and an img inside a parent div.

I assume if I click on top of the parent div, the img will be set to visible as below.

The img is not rendered visible when I click on the parent div. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function displayLock(display_square) {
  if (display_square == 4) {
    document.getElementById("sq4").style.visibility = "visible"
  }
}
```

```css
img#sq4 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="twenty-three" id="twenty-three">
  <div id="question">?</div>
  <img id="sq4" src="./lock_1.png" onclick="displayLock(4)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to click something invisible?

Comment: @mplungjan The parent div is visible. The img element is invisible. I want to be able to click on the img element to make it visible.

Comment: Then you need the event handler on something visible

Comment: Could you make your code more complete. For example you haven't shown us the code for lockSquare. And did yo mean to put the onclick onto the parent or the ? It makes no sense having it on the img.

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener is on the invisible element

Try this

```js
function displayLock() {
  document.getElementById(this.dataset.id).style.visibility = "visible"
}
document.getElementById("question").addEventListener("click",displayLock)
```

```css
img#sq4 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="twenty-three" id="twenty-three">
  <div id="question" data-id="sq4">?</div>
  <img id="sq4" alt="sq4" src="./lock_1.png"  />
</div>
```

Comment: I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" for document.getElementById("question")

Comment: do you have more than one element with id="question" then you need to use a class instead. If you have many, delegate from the container. Show more HTML. I am off to bed